# Lucene EdgeNGramTokenFilter scoring

Tags: java, filter, lucene

I'm using the filter `EdgeNGramTokenFilter` during the indexation.

When I'm looking for a word. Lucene doesn't make difference in its scoring when it find a full word or a part of another one.

For example if I'm looking for the word PUB.
I would like to see every PUB on the top of the result and after only the word PUBLIC.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I create two fields, one will be analyzed (edgeNgrams), one will be not

```
TextField field = new TextField(FULLTEXT_COL, value, Field.Store.NO);
d.add(field);
//exact search
Field exactField = new TextField(FullTextIndexationManager.EXACT_COL + FULLTEXT_COL, value, Field.Store.NO);                    
d.add(exactField);
```

I use a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper to assign analyser

```
Map<String, Analyzer> analyzerPerField = new HashMap<>();
analyzerPerField.put(FullTextIndexationManager.EXACT_COL + FULLTEXT_COL, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44));
PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper aWrapper = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper(customAnalyzer, analyzerPerField);
```

When I search in both fields

```
keys.add(FullTextIndexationManager.FULLTEXT_COL);
    values.add(QueryParser.escape(value));
    occurs.add(BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    //exact search
    keys.add(FullTextIndexationManager.EXACT_COL+FullTextIndexationManager.FULLTEXT_COL);
    values.add(QueryParser.escape(value));
    occurs.add(BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    Query q = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_44, queries, fields, flags, ontologySearch.getAnalyzer());
```

when i will find a exact term it will score twice